# Error when using 3 layers to retrieve the data from the tables in C#

Tags: c#, oop

I am new in C# and tried to follow 3 layers program for Database handle by C# Windows Form as the following:
I have:
DAL layer:

```
public class DAL_TreeView
{
  public DataTable GetAllTmsa(DTO_TreeView tmsa)
     {
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM " + tmsa.tmsaTables + "";
        //string sql = "SELECT * from " + TMSATable + "";
        SqlConnection con = DAL_TMSA_Connection.ConnectDB();
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();
        return dt;

    }
}
```

DTO layer:

```
public class DTO_TreeView
{
   public string tmsaTables { get; set; }

}
```

BUS Layer:

```
 public class BUS_TreeView
    {
       DAL_TreeView BUSdaltmsa = new DAL_TreeView();
          public DataTable GetTmsaTable(DTO_TreeView dtoTmsa)
        {
            return BUSdaltmsa.GetAllTmsa(dtoTmsa);
        }
    }
```

Presentation Layer:

```
// I want to retrieve data form tables by taking the name of the table from the list in the combobox cmbTMSAList.

public partial class FrmMainForm : Form
{
    BUS_TreeView busTreeiew = new BUS_TreeView();
    DAL_TreeView dalTreeiew = new DAL_TreeView();
    DTO_TreeView dtoTreeview = new DTO_TreeView();        
    DataTable TreeViewParent_dt = new DataTable();


    public FrmMainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }     

    private void cmbTMSAList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)// Select TMSA Table for TreeView
    {
        dtoTreeview.tmsaTables = cmbTMSAList.Text;
        //Get the name of the table from the combobox
    }

    private void TreeView1Populate()
    {
        treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
        TreeViewParent_dt = busTreeiew.GetTmsaTable(dtoTreeview);
        TreeNodeCollection parentnode = treeView1.Nodes;
        PopulateTreeView(parentnode, 0, TreeViewParent_dt);
        ComboBoxElementUpLoad();

    }
}
```

When I ran, the Error appeared at the code: `adapter.Fill(dt);` with the following content:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was unhandled by user code
  Class=16
  ErrorCode=-2146232060
  HResult=-2146232060
  LineNumber=1
  Message=Invalid object name 'System.Data.DataRowView'.
  Number=208
  Procedure=""
  Server=172.16.3.234,1433
  Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
  State=1
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,       Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException      exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
       at         System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject  stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,  SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout,  Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean  describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
       at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
       at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
       at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
       at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
       at DAL_TMSA.DAL_TreeView.GetAllTmsa(DTO_TreeView tmsa) in C:\Users\lamphuctu\OneDrive\00CSharp\TMSA_MONITOR\DAL_TMSA\DAL_TreeView.cs:line 41
       at BUS_TMSA.BUS_TreeView.GetTmsaTable(DTO_TreeView dtoTmsa) in  C:\Users\lamphuctu\OneDrive\00CSharp\TMSA_MONITOR\BUS_TMSA\BUS_TreeView.cs:line 23
       at TMSA_MONITOR.FrmMainForm.TreeView1Populate() in C:\Users\lamphuctu\OneDrive\00CSharp\TMSA_MONITOR\TMSA_MONITOR\FrmMainForm.cs:line 124
       at TMSA_MONITOR.FrmMainForm.cmbTMSAList_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) in  C:\Users\lamphuctu\OneDrive\00CSharp\TMSA_MONITOR\TMSA_MONITOR\FrmMainForm.cs:lin e 135
       at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.set_SelectedIndex(Int32 value)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.RefreshItems()
       at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.OnDataSourceChanged(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.SetDataConnection(Object newDataSource, BindingMemberInfo newDisplayMember, Boolean force)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.set_DataSource(Object value)
   InnerException:
```

and

> {"Invalid object name 'System.Data.DataRowView'."

So kindly help to find the reason.

Comment: Can you repost with the code correctly formatted please?

Comment: You need to post the stack trace, as it contains much contextual information about the error.

Comment: I would like to retrieve the tables into the main Form those are copied from the original table in the same Database. I have the list of these tables and populate into the combobox (cmbTMSAList), by selection the name of one of these table I pass the variable (name of the table) to DTO (Entity) layer then BUS and DAL layers will proceed with the name of the table to retrieve into the main Form (Presentation Layer) but error.  Mean while I can give the name of one of the table in the DAL layer, it works successfully. Please help me to find the reason. Thanks

Comment: I tried to add reference Presentation to DAL layer then use using Presentation to get directly the name of the table - parameter (variable) from Presentation (not via DTO and BUS layer) but impossible. C# give the warning: "A reference to 'Presentation_Layer' could not be added. Adding this project as a reference would cause a circular dependency"

Comment: People need to see the stack trace to determine where the error is occurring. The text that you have replaced with *(many more)* in your question is actually very important.

Comment: I had posted stack trace onto my question, kindly advise. Thanks

Comment: It's a `SqlException`, so there's an error in your SQL syntax. Set a breakpoint and inspect the value of `sql` before you try to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `cmbTMSAList.Text` in the line below is returning the value "System.Data.DataRowView" which is not a valid table in your database (hence, the message *Invalid object name 'System.Data.DataRowView'*).

`dtoTreeview.tmsaTables = cmbTMSAList.Text;`

Comment: Thank you, I will check and revert soon

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Jeyoung, I found the reason why it caused error by using the below code:
       private void cmbTMSAList_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cmbTMSAList.Text != "System.Data.DataRowView")
            {
                dtoTreeview.tmsaTables = cmbTMSAList.Text;
                MessageBox.Show("Name of the table: " + dtoTreeview.tmsaTables, "Information");
                TreeView1Populate();
            }
        }
So I can pass the name of the tables to DAL layer to populate the treeview by selection from the combobox. But I surprised that why C# gives System.Data.DataRowView to combobox at the initial state when loading the data to it? It may happen to Listbox and other also. However I found the solution. Thanks again.